# Scrambled text preview of pdf files in ranger

Tags: pdf, ranger

I'm using ranger to preview/open and rename a number of pdf files. However if the file is open and I navigate back to the terminal window running ranger and then scroll to another file, the text preview in the ranger session (which I believe is the the result of `pdftotext file.pdf -`) gets scrambled. Then after closing the pdf file the whole ranger session becomes unusable.

Is it possible to disable the `pdftotext` preview of files in ranger?

Running Fedora v31.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Forgot that there was an option to preview image/pdf files within ranger itself, which makes the problem redundant. In that case I hadn't yet installed `w3m` and `w3m-img`.

My `scope.sh` file was also missing and so I needed to run: `ranger --copy-config=all` first. Commenting out the lines

```
    # PDF
    pdf)
        # Preview as text conversion
        pdftotext -l 10 -nopgbrk -q -- "${FILE_PATH}" - | fmt -w ${PV_WIDTH} && exit 5
        mutool draw -F txt -i -- "${FILE_PATH}" 1-10 | fmt -w ${PV_WIDTH} && exit 5
        exiftool "${FILE_PATH}" && exit 5
        exit 1;;
```

in the `handle_extension()` function (within `scope.sh`) disables `pdftotext` preview. It does not however totally fix the "scrambled text", just reduces it. This is because by default in the `i3wm` new windows appear side by side, and ranger doesn't seem to handle the resizing window well.

Useful links:

1. https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/329451/scope-sh-is-lacking-for-ranger-file-manager
2. https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/407116/preview-pdf-as-image-in-ranger
3. https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/150135/ranger-image-preview-with-transparent-terminal-background
4. https://www.reddit.com/r/suckless/comments/ca648j/st_unable_to_display_preview_images_in_ranger/
5. https://github.com/ranger/ranger/pull/995/commits/ab8fd9e8256a1a6c296934af6ffb77bd34671bb2